# Does there exist a graph with chromatic number 4 that has no triangle or square cycles?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

$K_4$ is an example of a graph that requires 4 colours to be coloured but it contains triangle cycles and a square cycle too.

I've tried drawing ever more complicated graphs made up of pentagons, hexagons, etc. but I've been able to colour all of them with 3 colours.

If such a graph exists without any triangle or square cycles does anyone have a hint as to how I could discover it?

Comment: You could use Mycielski's construction (google it) to create triangle-free graphs having arbitrarily large chromatic numbers. As for squares, I don't know at present.

Comment: I tried using Mycielski on a couple of examples, but it seems that it does create 4-cycles…so the search goes on…

Answer (score 3):

Brinkmann graph has chromatic number 4 and girth 5 (so it has no cycles of length 3 or 4)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brinkmann_graph

Other such graphs:

Foster Cage : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FosterCage.html

Wells graph (again on MathWorld, but I can't post the link...)

EDIT, by the way, it has been proved (I think Erdos among the others) that there exists always a graph with girth > a and chromatic number > b for every a and b. Search: high girth high chromatic number theorem on google.